# Type of iterator for range-based for loop

Tags: c++11, for-loop

Say I have the following code:

```
std::vector<std::string> foo({"alice", "bob"});
for (const std::string &f : foo)
    std::cout << f.size() << std::endl;
```

if I make a mistake and change `f.size()` to `f->size()`, I get the following error from GCC:

> error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘**const string {aka
>   const std::basic_string}**

Why is the actual type `const std::basic_string<char>` rather than `const std::basic_string<char> &` (reference)?

Comment: What leads you to think it is not `const std::basic_string<char> &`?

Comment: the somewhat cryptic compiler message probably..

Comment: What does this have to do with iterators? Because `f` isn't an iterator.

Comment: @NicolBolas quite right, I should have said, "Type of iterated element...".

Comment: @tmatth: Then change your question to say that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The left-hand side of `->` operator is an expression. There ain't no such thing as an expression with a reference type:

> 5p5 If an expression initially has the type “reference to T” (8.3.2, 8.5.3), the type is adjusted to T prior to any further analysis. The expression designates the object or function denoted by the reference, and the expression is an lvalue or an xvalue, depending on the expression.